# While nextLine() not equal ""

Tags: java, string, input, while-loop

Im trying to go on a loop while the input file has a string on the following line but im getting an error. Any idea why?

```
while( !((input = in.nextLine()).equals(""))){
   ...
}
```

Output:

```
Enter file name: input1.txt
evil live
Exception in thread "main" This is a palindrome
level
This is a palindrome
dog
Not a palindrome
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
    at Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:41)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not correct, because it is possible that the input would end without providing an empty line. You should check if a line is available before checking it for being empty:

```
while(in.hasNextLine() && !((input = in.nextLine()).equals(""))){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no line after the end of file. When the last line is read the next call to `nextLine()` will fail. Use [`hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) to protect against this.

Answer (score 1):

`in.nextLine()` is probably returning a null, which is being assigned to `input`, which you are trying to invoke `equals` on.

Use `hasNextLine` ([documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29)) to make sure you can get the next line.

Answer (score 1):

The way your loop is setup, it will never reach a "" string because it will hit the end of the file before doing so. it should be something like

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    ...
}
```

This means that it will continue until the file has no next line.

Answer (score 1):

Compare against `null` as well to check against `End-Of-File`

as

```
  while(((input = in.nextLine())!= null) && !(input.equals(""))){
```

Or try:

```
  while(in.hasNextLine(){
       input = in.nextLine();
        if(input != null && !(input.equals(""))){
          ........
        }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but im getting this: Enter file name: input1.txt
evil live
This is a palindrome
level
This is a palindrome
dog
Not a palindrome
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
 at Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:41)

Comment: Are you referring my updated answer? If yes, do me a favor. Put a debugger and check the value of `in.nextLine()` just before when it fails and share me.

Comment: I added another approach. Please try and let me know, if that works. If not, please let me know exception with line of origination.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this type of thing, catching the exception if needed:

```
input = in.nextLine();
while( !(input.equals(""))){
...
}
```

and if it throws an error, then set up a try...catch loop

Answer (score 0):

May be you need,

```
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    input = in.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner throws an exception when it runs out of input. You seem to be thinking that it will return a zero-length string.

Are you using Scanner to read a file a line at a time? That's not what it's for. You may want to look at BufferedReader.